# Sci-Fi Movie, Rich living in space and poor people in earth

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I have seen this movie years ago and only has some vague ideas. I would like to watch it again. That's why I am looking to find it's name.

I think it's release after 2005, most probably close to 2010 (not sure). English (Hollywood I think).

The main character (male), has some secrets copied into his brain or a chip in his brain or something. The rich are living in a city built in space with all facilities. Poor are living in earth which is a junk place and without any facility. Some kind of robotic police patrols the earth. There is a human police official who is cruel and sadistic. The one who live in the space city control everything.

The main character met with a lady. She has a daughter, who is ill. She will live only if she get proper medical care that is available in space (I think that's is some kind of ultra modern rejuvenating thing or something like that which cures any health problem).

The hero joins a team who were trying to build an aircraft to reach the space city from earth illegally and helps them. They all reach the space city in their aircraft and fights going on and don't has clear idea about what happened in the end. I thin the cruel police got killed and the medical facility gets available for all needy, who were in earth too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

["Elysium" (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1535108/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

IMDb:

> "**In the year 2154, the very wealthy live on a man-made space station
>   while the rest of the population resides on a ruined Earth.** A man
>   takes on a mission that could bring equality to the polarized worlds."

Detailed plot [on Wikipedia here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysium_(film))

Early in the trailer below you can see the patrolling robot police officers.

Trailer: